# Silence Ruby regular expression warning

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a `-` in my regular expression. When I run it, I get `warning: character class has '-' without escape: /[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]/`

How can I silence this warning?

Comment: Why don't you move `-` to the front (or back) of your character class or use `\-` to avoid the warning in the first place?

Comment: When you post a question, try to give  a minimum example that reproduces the issue. I simplified the regex.

Comment: Try this: `[^\w.-]`. Not sure if backslash before dot is to escape dot or include backslash into the class, but if you want to have backslash in the set as well use `[^\w.\\-]`

Comment: Amazing a language, ruby in this case, recognizes this particular dash `-` is not a range operator. It goes through all the trouble of telling you this in an exception, when it's obviously _non-ambiguous_ and should be treated as a literal. They must think regex programmers are children.

Comment: @sln It's almost like it's really easy to accidentally type `az-0-9` instead of `a-z0-9` and rapid warning of potential issues is useful. Maybe that's just for us "children", though -- an "adult" like yourself is doubtlessly perfect in every way and never makes little typos.

Comment: @NicHartley  - `z-0` is not a _**range operator**_ error, it's a _range_ error, which probably is a typo. But, in no-man's land, the place between entities, all is literal. By your logic, putting a `^` or a `[` in the middle of a class should be an error that the children should not do. Some engines became enlightened and let the range operator be a literal in no-mans land a long time ago. Perl and pcre for example.

Comment: @sln ...You realize Ruby does, too? That's why it's a _warning_, not an error. It's _warning_ you that, hey, you might not have mean to do that, because that could really easily be a typo. And, since you don't seem to want to realize that a quick example doesn't need to be perfect to get the point across, fine. `09-a-z` is equally likely, wouldn't be caught by your check, and is still likely to be wrong. It's _possible_ that it's right, but then the programmer would know that, and either ignore the warning or take it as a sign that they should make their code clearer.

Comment: @NicHartley - You know, it's been nice talking to you. I don't think you can pick and choose what looks  _likely wrong_ but passes _my_ tests. The likelihood of this `[ [-\xFF]` being wrong is higher, but it throws no warnings. I know how regex's are parse, and I can tell you if this `-` is between entities it has _no business_ emitting any warning or error at all. The list is endless of what _may look suspicious_ but lets get past _warning_ the children, ok ?

Answer (score 0):

At this place `[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]` there is a possibility of an error. Usage of '-' either means the new range(with mistyping) or just a symbol. Either move single characters in front of ranges or prefix with '\'

Comment: Not quite. Warning means that there is no syntactic problem (hence no ambiguity), but that the user might have intended something different from what it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Add a backslash (`\`) to escape the lonely dash.  It appears the offending dash is immediately after `[^a-zA-Z0-9`. Add `\-` instead of just the dash character `-`.  The full regex including the minor change is

`/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_\\.]/`

This will remove the warning. Escaping it with the backslash clearly instructs the regex engine that you mean to search for that character and not that you forgot to complete a range like `[a-z]`

Answer (score 0):

```
verbosity = $VERBOSE
$VERBOSE = nil
/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]/ #=> /[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]/
$VERBOSE = verbosity
```

Comment: Hmmm, not how I interpreted the question, but definitely directly addresses it.  Nice!